# Dayjs relative time thresholds don't work

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I've got a problem with thresholds and rounding using Dayjs relativeTime. I've set thresholds and extend dayjs, but it still use default options and I have no idea why.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';

const thresholds = [
    { l: 's', r: 1 },
    { l: 'm', r: 1 },
    { l: 'mm', r: 59, d: 'minute' },
    { l: 'h', r: 1 },
    { l: 'hh', r: 23, d: 'hour' },
    { l: 'd', r: 1 },
    { l: 'dd', r: 29, d: 'day' },
    { l: 'M', r: 1 },
    { l: 'MM', r: 11, d: 'month' },
    { l: 'y' },
    { l: 'yy', d: 'year' },
];
const rounding = Math.floor;
const config = { thresholds, rounding };
dayjs.extend(relativeTime, config);
```

Based on code above, with input `dayjs('2022-01-01').to(dayjs('2022-01-28'))` it should output `28 days`, but the actual output is `1 month`. It happens with number of days above 25, which is default value.